# Where to put "sometimes" in a negative sentence?

Tags: word-usage

They don't sometimes play tennis at a club on Sundays.
They sometiems don't play tennis at a club on Sundays.

So, which sentence is correct? Where should we put frequency adverbs like "sometimes" in a negative sentence?

Comment: Sometimes they don't play tennis on Sundays.

Comment: They’re both grammatical. It’s unclear what your intent is.  “They don’t sometimes play tennis at a club on Sundays, they ***always*** play tennis at a club on Sundays.”  “They sometimes don’t play tennis at a club on Sundays, sometimes they play at the park.”

Comment: Both option are incorrect; no native speaker would use these phrases.  As @HotLicks noted, the only correct version is "Sometimes they don't play tennis on Sundays.".  However, this question would be more appropriate in the English Language Learners community.

Comment: To be idiomatic, the sentence needs to be more elaborate, as Jim suggests. "They play tennis on Sundays, sometimes at a club and sometimes at the park." "They sometimes go for a long walk on Sundays instead of playing tennis." Or, to make it a definite negative, you could say "They don't _always_ play tennis on Sundays."